# Can I create a List of functions in python?

Tags: python, list, function, random

I am trying to create a list of functions in my program in order to use the random module to randomly choose. in theory it look and work with this

```
import random

def test1():
  print("1st function")

def test2():
  print("2nd function")

def test3():
  print("3rd function")

def test_func():
  test_list = [test1(), test2(), test3()]
  apple = random.choice(test_list)
  return print(apple)

test_func()
```

the result of this is it prints out test_list and prints "NONE" for apple is there a way to get it to randomly pick a function and only print that function.

Comment: `test1` is the function. `test1()` is the result of calling the function

Answer (score 1):

you should add function reference to the list and call the function after.

```
def test_func():
  test_list = [test1, test2, test3]
  apple = random.choice(test_list)()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just don't call the functions when you put them in the list:

```
import random

def test1():
  print("1st function")

def test2():
  print("2nd function")

def test3():
  print("3rd function")

def test_func():
  test_list = [test1, test2, test3]
  apple = random.choice(test_list)
  return apple() #won't return anything due to it being a print function

test_func()
```

Comment: thank you very simple solution when I tried that it did no longer print the functions. however apple returned as "<function test1 at 0x7f97c74a21f0>" how do I get it to print

Comment: did you call apple? See in the print function in test_func you have to put brackets after `apple`

Comment: I changed the code to "pple = random.choice(test_list)()" and it worked perfectly

Comment: Don't forget to return it too, if the list of functions return anything themselves (although see the comment in my code for this example case)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are assigning the list the return values of the functions you created. Since they do not have a return value, it will be None.

What you need to do is assign the function itself by removing the parenthesis. You would also need to call the `apple` function by adding the parenthesis to it, not by printing it. So, your code will look like this:

```py
import random


def test1():
    print("1st function")


def test2():
    print("2nd function")


def test3():
    print("3rd function")


def test_func():
    test_list = [test1, test2, test3]
    apple = random.choice(test_list)
    apple()


test_func()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def test1():
    print("1st function")
    #This returns "None"
```

The reason you are getting "None" printed to console is because you are printing the function, which does return a NoneType. Return defaults to None if not specified. To make it only print the desired function remove the line `return print(apple)`

You would also want to store references to your functions:

```
test_list = [test1, test2, test3]
```

so that they are not executed. Then you can run `apple()` to execute them in your main function.